# Getting some values as <null> in iOS but working fine in Postman and Android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to hit the following URL ( https://api.cinepass.de/v4/cinemas/?countries=IN&apikey=oMOLF6O1HfCt8XikVP4vnZ2V2EWiX8rn )  using GET method in iOS (Objective-c) and getting the following response

```
{
    id = 20330;
    "poster_image_thumbnail" = "<null>";
    slug = "xxx-return-of-xander-cage";
    title = "<null>";
}
```

I'm getting values of title and poster_image_thumbnail as "null" and also double quotes are missing for id, slug and title.

If I hit the same URL in Chrome (Windows) and Android Studio. I'm getting the following response.

```
{
        "id": "20330",
        "slug": "xxx-return-of-xander-cage",
        "title": "xXx: Return of Xander Cage",
        "poster_image_thumbnail": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/9A9vKtJ82KHGaOE3fzl4J3PJyqq.jpg"
}
```

Surprisingly, I'm getting wrong response (first one) if I open the same URL in Chrome (MAC).

Am I missing something ?

URL: https://api.cinepass.de/v4/movies/?countries=IN&apikey=oMOLF6O1HfCt8XikVP4vnZ2V2EWiX8rn

Documentation: https://api.cinepass.de/documentation/v4/#movies_get

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: You need to post code. Also, what you noticed for the "quotes missing", is just about the `-description` (it's just to say that it's in one part, essentially when there are space, underscores, etc.), and the most important thing, is that you have "=" and not ":", meaning it's already a JSON serialized into in that case a NSDictionary.